# Does Elementary run smoothly natively? [Slow and Buggy on Virtualbox]

Tags: virtualbox

Is there a known issue with Elementary OS and Virtualbox? I searched here but didn't find anything this specifically or recent. Does it run well natively?

Context:
I was deciding whether I would install Ubuntu GNOME or Elementary OS on my machine, so I ran both on Virtualbox. And Elementary is absolutely awful there. 
I gave it 8gb of ram and it's quite slow. So buggy, stuff just stop working after a while.
Since the OS gets a lot of praise I assume it's not like that. I'm asking so I decide if worth the trouble installing it.

Answer (score 2):

There is some outstanding issue with VirtualBox hardware acceleration not working properly for 3D rendering. This has been known to cause significant performance issues, and is not representative of normal installs.

Comment: This issue seems to still exist as of today. Do you have any reference to more information? Running debian and running Ubuntu in VirtualBox works nicely, also with 3D acceleration (and it shows decent performance). With elementaryOS I have to completely disable 3D acceleration, otherwise the system is almost unusable. If it works for the other two, I see no reason why it would not work for elementaryOS as well.

Comment: I think this is likely something to do with the window manager gala being used not having support within both itself, and within virtualbox. Both systems must support each other, to some extent.